# Retrieve Facebook user interests after custom login button is pressed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the user interests after the user authenticates with Facebook, for the authentication I modified the sample project supplied by Facebook for custom Facebook login button.

You can find my attempt app here:

[source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nigbqk6opx6okol/FBLoginCustomUISample.zip?dl=0)

The error that I get is this:

Error for request to endpoint '/me/likes': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have duplicated this question and managed to answer it myself, here is the answer and conclusion I have implemented:**

- [My Other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810016/retrieve-facebook-pages-likes-using-custom-login-button)